# XSL Transform does not work unlesss xml nodes are in specific order

Tags: xml, xslt

I have pasted stripped down versions of my XML and XSLT below.

I have almost got what I need but I can't seem to get a total row for 'Class 2' if the xml is ordered as below.

The first 2 orderline elements both have a Class attribute of 'No Class'.  If I put these elements last then the transformation works.  However the xml is received in the order below and so needs to work like this.

Teh order of the xml seems to be the problem so I was thinking that perhaps it would be possible to sort the xml and put into a variable then I could transform the contents of the variable. Is it possible to do things that way in xslt

Can anyone help?

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE EmailOrder 
  SYSTEM "http://orders.bbb.co.uk/xml/Xorder.DTD">
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='BBSORG6.XSL'?>
<EmailOrders>
  <Order Key="COLGRE1-20140914-2345">
    <Customer_Msg>Class sort</Customer_Msg>
    <OrderLine>
      <OrderKey>COLGRE1-20140914-2345</OrderKey>
      <ProductKey>1001</ProductKey>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Free>0</Free>
      <Cost>12.99</Cost>
      <VAT_rate>0</VAT_rate>
      <Details>Friends Character Encyclopedia   </Details>
      <Class>No Class</Class>
      <Bags>0</Bags>
      <Section>Funfare</Section>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <OrderKey>COLGRE1-20140914-2345</OrderKey>
      <ProductKey>1002</ProductKey>
      <Qty>2</Qty>
      <Free>0</Free>
      <Cost>19.98</Cost>
      <VAT_rate>0</VAT_rate>
      <Details>Winnie’s Big Bad Robot</Details>
      <Class>No Class</Class>
      <Bags>0</Bags>
      <Section>Funfare</Section>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <OrderKey>COLGRE1-20140914-2345</OrderKey>
      <ProductKey>1012</ProductKey>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Free>0</Free>
      <Cost>6.50</Cost>
      <VAT_rate>0</VAT_rate>
      <Details>Snow</Details>
      <Class>Class 1</Class>
      <Bags>5</Bags>
      <Section>Funfare</Section>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <OrderKey>COLGRE1-20140914-2345</OrderKey>
      <ProductKey>1088</ProductKey>
      <Qty>2</Qty>
      <Free>0</Free>
      <Cost>17.98</Cost>
      <VAT_rate>0</VAT_rate>
      <Details>Great Fairy Bake Off</Details>
      <Class>Class 1</Class>
      <Bags>5</Bags>
      <Section>Funfare</Section>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <OrderKey>COLGRE1-20140914-2345</OrderKey>
      <ProductKey>1123</ProductKey>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Free>0</Free>
      <Cost>3.99</Cost>
      <VAT_rate>0</VAT_rate>
      <Details>Space</Details>
      <Class>Class 1</Class>
      <Bags>5</Bags>
      <Section>Funfare</Section>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <OrderKey>COLGRE1-20140914-2345</OrderKey>
      <ProductKey>1001</ProductKey>
      <Qty>2</Qty>
      <Free>0</Free>
      <Cost>25.98</Cost>
      <VAT_rate>0</VAT_rate>
      <Details>Friends Character Encyclopedia   </Details>
      <Class>Class 2</Class>
      <Bags>4</Bags>
      <Section>Funfare</Section>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <OrderKey>COLGRE1-20140914-2345</OrderKey>
      <ProductKey>1002</ProductKey>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Free>0</Free>
      <Cost>9.99</Cost>
      <VAT_rate>0</VAT_rate>
      <Details>Winnie’s Big Bad Robot</Details>
      <Class>Class 2</Class>
      <Bags>4</Bags>
      <Section>Funfare</Section>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <OrderKey>COLGRE1-20140914-2345</OrderKey>
      <ProductKey>1012</ProductKey>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <Free>0</Free>
      <Cost>6.50</Cost>
      <VAT_rate>0</VAT_rate>
      <Details>Snow</Details>
      <Class>Class 2</Class>
      <Bags>4</Bags>
      <Section>Funfare</Section>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <OrderKey>COLGRE1-20140914-2345</OrderKey>
      <ProductKey>1023</ProductKey>
      <Qty>10</Qty>
      <Free>0</Free>
      <Cost>69.90</Cost>
      <VAT_rate>0</VAT_rate>
      <Details>The Witch with an Itch</Details>
      <Class>Class 2</Class>
      <Bags>4</Bags>
      <Section>Funfare</Section>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <OrderKey>COLGRE1-20140914-2345</OrderKey>
      <ProductKey>1333</ProductKey>
      <Qty>2</Qty>
      <Free>0</Free>
      <Cost>19.98</Cost>
      <VAT_rate>0</VAT_rate>
      <Details>Scientriffic: Planet Earth</Details>
      <Class>Class 2</Class>
      <Bags>4</Bags>
      <Section>Book Zone</Section>
    </OrderLine>
  </Order>
</EmailOrders>
```

The XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="EmailOrders/Order"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Order">
    <TABLE WIDTH="65%" BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="4" 
           bgcolor="yellow" align="center">
      <TR ALIGN="left">
        <TD>Customer message</TD>
        <TD>
          <xsl:value-of select="Customer_Msg"/>
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <BR/>
    <BR/>
    <TABLE WIDTH="100%" BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="4"
           bgcolor="lightyellow" rules="cols" align="center">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Customer_Msg = 'Class sort' ">
          <THEAD>
            <TH>Class</TH>
            <TH>List</TH>
            <TH>Paid</TH>
            <TH>Free</TH>
            <TH>No.</TH>
            <TH>Title</TH>
            <TH>Price</TH>
          </THEAD>
          <xsl:for-each select="OrderLine">
            <xsl:sort select="Class"/>
            <xsl:sort select="ProductKey"/>
            <TR ALIGN="left">
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Class"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Section"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Qty"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Free"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="ProductKey"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Details"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Cost"/>
              </TD>
            </TR>
            <xsl:if test="Class != following::Class[1] or position() = last()">
              <xsl:variable name="LastClass">
                <xsl:value-of select="Class"/>
              </xsl:variable>
              <TR ALIGN="left" bgcolor="lightblue">
                <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="$LastClass"/> Totals</TD>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="Bags"/> Bags</TD>
                <TD>
                  <xsl:value-of select="sum(/EmailOrders
                                        /Order/OrderLine
                                        [Class=$LastClass]/Qty)"/>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                  <xsl:value-of select="sum(/EmailOrders
                                        /Order/OrderLine
                                        [Class=$LastClass]/Free)"/>
                </TD>
                <TD/>
                <TD/>
                <TD>
                  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(
                                        sum(
                                        /EmailOrders
                                        /Order/OrderLine
                                        [Class=$LastClass]/Cost),
                                        '#####.##')"/>
                </TD>
              </TR>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <TR ALIGN="left" bgcolor="lightseagreen">
            <TD>Order totals</TD>
            <TD/>
            <TD>
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(/EmailOrders
                                    /Order/OrderLine/Qty)"/>
            </TD>
            <TD>
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(/EmailOrders
                                    /Order/OrderLine/Free)"/>
            </TD>
            <TD/>
            <TD/>
            <TD>
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(/EmailOrders
                                    /Order/OrderLine/Cost),
                                    '#####.##')"/>
            </TD>
          </TR>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <THEAD>
            <TH>List</TH>
            <TH>Paid</TH>
            <TH>Free</TH>
            <TH>Ref</TH>
            <TH>Title</TH>
            <TH>Total</TH>
          </THEAD>
          <xsl:for-each select="OrderLine">
            <xsl:sort select="ProductKey"/>
            <TR ALIGN="left">
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Section"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Qty"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Free"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="ProductKey"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Details"/>
              </TD>
              <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Cost"/>
              </TD>
            </TR>
            <xsl:if test="Section != following::Section[1] 
                          or position() = last()">
              <xsl:variable name="LastSection">
                <xsl:value-of select="Section"/>
              </xsl:variable>
              <TR ALIGN="left" bgcolor="lightblue">
                <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="Section"/> totals</TD>
                <TD>
                  <xsl:value-of select="sum(/EmailOrders
                                        /Order/OrderLine
                                        [Section=$LastSection]/Qty)"/>
                </TD>
                <TD>
                  <xsl:value-of select="sum(/EmailOrders
                                        /Order/OrderLine
                                        [Section=$LastSection]/Free)"/>
                </TD>
                <TD/>
                <TD/>
                <TD>
                  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(
                                        sum(/EmailOrders
                                        /Order/OrderLine
                                        [Section=$LastSection]
                                        /Cost),
                                        '#####.##')"/>
                </TD>
              </TR>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <TR ALIGN="left" bgcolor="lightseagreen">
            <TD>Order totals</TD>
            <TD>
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(/EmailOrders
                                    /Order/OrderLine/Qty)"/>
            </TD>
            <TD>
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(/EmailOrders
                                    /Order/OrderLine/Free)"/>
            </TD>
            <TD/>
            <TD/>
            <TD>
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number(
                                    sum(/EmailOrders
                                    /Order/OrderLine
                                    /Cost),
                                    '#####.##')"/>
            </TD>
          </TR>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </TABLE>
    <BR/>
    <BR/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your stylesheet says version 2.0; are you sure you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: Maybe not.  These sheets are just files are just being opened in the browser and printed. Generally firefox or IE9 I think.

Comment: No browser supports XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes down to this line (Or the similar line for the `Section` element.

```
<xsl:if test="Class != following::Class[1] or position() = last()">
```

The use of the `following` axes here does not depend to the order the `Class` elements have been sorted, but the order of the `Class` elements in the original document. This is why you are getting different results when you re-order the document.

How to solve it? Well, you need to take another approach. This is actually an example of a grouping problem. With such problems the version of XSLT you can use is important because grouping is handled differently in XSLT 2.0 than it is in XSLT 1.0.

You're stylesheet has `version="2.0"` specified, but you are also using the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt` and Microsoft has no love for XSLT 1.0. (You can run XSLT 2.0 stylesheets with a XSLT 1.0 processor, but it will just ignore commands it does not recognise)

Assuming XSLT 1.0, you would use a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)

Concentrating purely of the `Class` element for the purposes of this answer, you would define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="OrderLine" match="OrderLine" use="Class" />
```

You would then get the distinct `Class` elements, which form the start of each group, like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="OrderLine[generate-id() = generate-id(key('OrderLine', Class)[1])]">
   <xsl:sort select="Class"/>
```

And to get the `OrderLine` elements that make up the group (i.e all `OrderLine` elements with the same class, you would do this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('OrderLine', Class)">
    <xsl:sort select="ProductKey"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

The `key` function could also be used to sum the total for the class.

Try this (very simplified) XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="OrderLine" match="OrderLine" use="Class" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="EmailOrders/Order"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <TABLE>
        <THEAD>
            <TH>Class</TH>
            <TH>No.</TH>
            <TH>Title</TH>
            <TH>Price</TH>
        </THEAD>
        <xsl:for-each select="OrderLine[generate-id() = generate-id(key('OrderLine', Class)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="Class"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('OrderLine', Class)">
                <xsl:sort select="ProductKey"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <TR>
                <TD><xsl:value-of select="Class"/> Totals</TD>
                <TD/>
                <TD/>
                <TD>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('OrderLine', Class)/Cost), '#####.##')"/>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <TR>
            <TD>Totals</TD>
            <TD/>
            <TD/>
            <TD>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(OrderLine/Cost), '#####.##')"/>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderLine">
        <TR ALIGN="left">
          <TD><xsl:value-of select="Class"/></TD>
          <TD><xsl:value-of select="ProductKey"/></TD>
          <TD><xsl:value-of select="Details"/></TD>
          <TD><xsl:value-of select="Cost"/></TD>
        </TR>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, if you could use XSLT 2.0, you could use the `xsl:for-each-group` command, like so

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="OrderLine" group-by="Class">
```

And, then instead of using the key to get the items in the group, you would use the `current-group` function. For example

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
    <xsl:sort select="ProductKey"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

And similarly in the sum

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Cost), '#####.##')"/>
```

Comment: This is the best answer I have ever received on stack overflow and I have received some good ones.  Thanks very much.  Have implemented successfully obviously using your first suggestion :)